# Documentation mistake for Search Optimization?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Noted under Search Optimization that in consideration of which Snowflake technology to use to improve performance the documentation on this page states that there is no storage cost to Clustering, see "Considering Other Solutions for Optimizing Query Performance"

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/search-optimization-service.html

This seems in contradiction to what is claim on this page about reclustering due to defining a clustering key, reclustering creates new micro-partitions but the superseded partitions are available for Time-Travel and Fail-Safe meaning you are gneerating new FDNs and thus charging for the new storage, correct?

See "Credit and Storage Impact of Reclustering"

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

The "Credit and Storage Impact of Reclustering" section is correct. Clustering can increase the storage costs but in my opinion, this cost is not in the same category with "Search Optimization Service" or "Materialized View". I think the table in the "Considering Other Solutions for Optimizing Query Performance" section is a simplified version, and shows only the direct costs of a feature. The storage costs because of "deleted but retained micro-partitions" is related with Time Travel and Fail-Safe features. So in theory, if your table is a transient table with 0 retention time (TT), the clustering will not cause any extra storage cost.

```
create or replace transient table t1 (a date, b varchar) 
cluster by (a)  DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS = 0 ;
```

On the other hand, when you enable "Materialized View" or "Search Optimization Service" on a table, these features will require extra storage space.

Comment: Yes, so there is an exception. Maybe that is what should added as a caveat to the claim.